# how to run pipeline only on HEAD commit in GitlabCi runner?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

we have a CI pipeline on our repository, hosted in gitlab

we setup [gitlab-runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) on our local machine

**the pipeline running 4 steps**

- build
- unit tests
- integration test
- quality tests

**all this pipeline takes almost 20 min**

and the pipeline trigger on each push to a branch

is there a way to configure the gitlab-runner that if the HEAD of a branch that the runner currently running on changes the pipe
will auto cancel the run? because the latest version is what matters

for example in this run the lower run is unnecessary

[image]

gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build
  - unit_tests
  - unit_and_integration_tests
  - quality_tests

build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - cd projects/ideology-synapse
  script:
    - mvn compile


unit_and_integration_tests:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  stage: unit_and_integration_tests
  only:
    - /^milestone-.*$/
  script:
    - export RUN_ENVIORMENT=GITLAB_CI
    - export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx32g"
    - mvn test
    - "cat */target/site/jacoco/index.html"
  cache: {}
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit:
        - "*/*/*/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml"


unit_tests:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone

  stage: unit_tests
  except:
    - /^milestone-.*$/
  script:
    - export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx32g"
    - mvn test
    - "cat */target/site/jacoco/index.html"
  cache: {}
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit:
        - "*/*/*/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml"

quality_tests:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  stage: quality_tests
  only:
    - /^milestone-.*$/
  script:
    - export RUN_ENVIORMENT_EVAL=GITLAB_CI
    - export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx32g"
    - mvn test
  cache: {}
```

edit after @siloko comment:

**I already try using
the auto-cancel redundant, pending pipelines in the setting menu**

**I want to cancel running pipelines and not pending**

Comment: There's a setting in your CI/CD settings called `Auto-cancel redundant, pending pipelines` Docs here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/settings.html#auto-cancel-pending-pipelines

Comment: I already mark this options and its still happened

Comment: I want to cancel running pipelines not pending

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after forther investigation, I found that I had 2 **active runners**
on one of my machines 
one **shared runner** , and another **specific runner** then if I push a 2 commit one after another to the same branch both of the runners take the jobs and execute them.
that also explains why

```
Auto-cancel redundant, pending pipelines
```

options, didn't work because it works only when the same runner have pending jobs

actions that been taken to fix this problem: unregister the specific runner and leave the machine only with the shared runner